# How to convert minute and hour integers to a "HHMM" time string in Java

Tags: java

I have two int variables as follows:

```
int minutes = 20;
int hours = 8;
```

How do I want to convert them to "HHMM" formation?

For the above, the result should be "0820".

Comment: Have you tried anything? For instance, have you had a look at `Calendar`?

Comment: or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: possibly String.formatter is sufficient

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to pad the variables to 2 digits each:

```
int minutes = 20;
int hours = 8;
String str = String.format("%02d%02d", hours, minutes);
System.out.println(str);
```

Prints:

```
0820
```

Look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Calendar` class as below:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
c.set(Calender.MINUTE, minutes);
```

In case you only want to format the values, you can use:

```
String str = String.format("%02d%02d", hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want it in a string which is simple. Just append them to a string.

```
String time = String.valueOf(hours) + String.valueOf(minutes);
if (hours < 10)
time = "0" +time;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display "0820" you can just paste them together in a string.

```
String hoursMinutes = String.format("%02d", hours) + String.format("%02d", minutes);
```